# How to make sideways table with horizontal text in a cell?

Tags: tables

I need to make such table in LaTeX:

[image]

I came up only with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\rotatebox{270}{
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
            First First & First Second\\ \hline
            Second First & Second Second  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}    
}
     \caption{Table 1}
    \label{table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But still don't know how to rotate the caption and how to add the cell with the horizontal text ("Existing solutions" cell).

EDIT:

I "almost" managed to do this, but still need the "existing solutions" cell. Any ideas?

Heres the code:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
  \centering 
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Features}} \\  \cline{2-9}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \textbf{\shortstack{}} & \textbf{\shortstack{}} & \textbf{\shortstack{}} &  \textbf{\shortstack{}} &  \textbf{\shortstack{}} & \textbf{\shortstack{}} &  \textbf{\shortstack{}} &  \textbf{\shortstack{}} \\
    \hline \shortstack{} &  &  & \shortstack{} & \shortstack{} &  &  & \shortstack{} &  \\ 
    \hline [25] & & & & & &  & & \\ 
    \hline [26] & & & & & &  & & \\ 
    \hline [27] & & & & & &  & & \\ 
    \hline [28] & & & & & &  & & \\ 
    \hline [29] & & & & & &  & & \\ 
    \hline [30] & & & & & &  & & \\ 
    \hline [31] & & & & & &  & & \\ 
    \hline [32] & & & & & &  & & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My caption}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

And it looks like this right now:

[image]

Comment: If this will take the whole page, You could use the `landscape` environment from `lscape` or `pdflscape` and then just rotate the contents of the one cell of the table?

Comment: And for `Existing solutions` use `\rotatebox` macro.

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape, array, rotating, multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        \hfill\turnbox{90}{Existing Solutions}\hfill & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        \phantom{X} & First First & First Second\\ \cline{2-3}
        & Second First & Second Second  \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{Table 1}
      \label{table1}
    \end{table}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

`array` isn't needed, I don't think, but it is always a good idea.

[image: Tabular in landscape]

If you would like to know why you should not format tabulars like this at all, see the `booktabs` documentation. (Arguably a slightly extreme stance but very useful for 99% of cases.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that adds the string "Existing solutions" via `\multirow` and `\rotatebox` instructions. The instruction `\multirow` is provided by the [multirow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/rotating) package, while `\rotatebox` is provided by the [graphicx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/graphics) package. (This package is loaded automatically by the `rotating` package, hence no need to load `graphicx` separately.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating,multirow}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % a handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{c|}} 
\cline{3-10}
\mc{} & & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{Features}} \\  
\cline{3-10}
\mc{} & & & & & & & & & \\ \hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\textbf{Existing solutions}}}
&      & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [25] & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [26] & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [27] & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [28] & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [29] & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [30] & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [31] & & & & & &  & & \\ \cline{2-10}
& [32] & & & & & &  & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{My caption}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```